# how to test for pywintypes.datetime type with isinstance?

Tags: python, pywin32

I am pulling a range from excel including dates. If I check for types this is what I get:

```
type(q)
Out[45]: 
pywintypes.datetime
q
Out[46]: 
pywintypes.datetime(2009, 10, 26, 0, 0, tzinfo=TimeZoneInfo('GMT Standard Time', True))
```

I am doing a check on it using `isinstance(q, pywintypes.datetime)` but it doesnt work.

```
isinstance(q, pywintypes.datetime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda2\envs\py36\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-47-916010697275>", line 1, in <module>
    isinstance(q, pywintypes.datetime)
AttributeError: module 'pywintypes' has no attribute 'datetime'
```

any idea how to test via isinstance to check if its a pywintypes object?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like this works:

```
from pywintypes import TimeType

if type(date) is TimeType:
    print('date!')
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below worked for me.  I couldn't get this "from pywintypes import TimeType" to work because I'm also using win32api which seems to interfere with TimeType.

```
import pywintypes
print(type(q) is pywintypes.TimeType)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try the following code:

```
import datetime

isinstance(q, datetime.datetime)
```