# Check numpy array which element has type pywintypes.datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime, strftime

I have a 2D numpy array of which elements are mostly strings but some of them are pywintypes.datetime.
Since it causes error when I pickle this object to a file, I will covert the pytwintypes.datetime to string using strftime command.

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <class 'pywintypes.datetime'>: attribute lookup datetime on pywintypes failed
```

If the entire column or row consists of pywintypes.datetime, it is not difficult, but it does not.

For a single element, I learned from [how to test for pywintypes.datetime type with isinstance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44656089/how-to-test-for-pywintypes-datetime-type-with-isinstance) that

```
import datetime
isinstance(q, datetime.datetime)
```

outputs the True/False whether it is datetime format.

How can I find out the indices or replace them without using loops?

Comment: Because you use a numpy array I think you have to run un a loop and try to convert.
You talk about a specific columns/rows that are in datetime format? if yes there's probably an easier solution

Comment: @EitanRosati No, it is not a whole row or column.

Comment: So it's object dtype?

Comment: So it's object dtype?